# C++ template function definition of a template class in source file

Tags: c++, templates

I am trying to solve a specific problem I have using templates in C++.
Basically I have a class called `Data`. Data can be either a matrix or a vector (a vector is a matrix with only one column) which can contain different datatypes.

---

## Code

#### Data.h

```
namespace nn {

template<typename T>
class Data {

    public:

    int width  = 0;
    int height = 0;
    int size   = 0;
    T* values  = nullptr;

    void   addTo(Data<T>* other);
    template<typename R>
    void   mulWith(Data<T>* other, Data<R>* target);
};

}
```

#### Data.cpp

```
template class nn::Data<float>;
template class nn::Data<double>;
template class nn::Data<int8_t>;
template class nn::Data<int16_t>;
template class nn::Data<int32_t>;
```

#### data_add.cpp

```
template<> void nn::Data<float>::addTo(Data<float> *other) {
    ...
}
...
```

The addition of two vectors / matrices works nicely. Sadly the issue with the multiplication is that the function takes the vector with which itself shall be multiplied aswell as the target vector where the result should be stored. The resulting vector can store different datatypes compared to the matrix itself.

e.g. `A * x = b` where A and x are `int8_t` but b is `int16_t`.
I need to write many different implementations for different combinations which wont be the problem. Sadly I am unable to get it to work in general.

I tried to do the following:

#### data_mul.cpp

```
template<> void nn::Data<int32_t>::mulWith(nn::Data<int8_t>* other, nn::Data<int16_t>* target){
    return;
}
```

which does not seem to work.

How would one correctly write the definitions of such functions?

I am very happy for any help!

Greetings
Finn

---

## Solution

Adding a second `template<>` does the job:

```
template<> template<> void nn::Data<int8_t>::mulWith<int32_t>(nn::Data<int8_t>* other, nn::Data<int32_t>* target){
```

Comment: [`std::common_type`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/common_type) may be useful.

Comment: Have you considered using two template parameters for the mulWith function (instead of just R) ?

Comment: Why would I need two of them? Ideally one comes directly from the class?

Comment: Well I am not quite sure what you are trying to achieve, put it seems that the class template gives the type to 'b' and the two additional parameters would be the types of 'A' and 'x'.

Comment: the class template is the type of the matrix (itself) and the vector is being multiplied with. R is supposed to be the type of the resulting vector

Comment: I may have mixed up the notations. The class template corresponds to 'A' type, the new template parameter could be used for 'other'/'x' and the current template parameter 'R' corresponds to 'b'

Comment: Okay so this seems to be getting somewhere. Thank you for all your help!

Answer (score 0):

First of all your example has a logical error already:

```
template<> void nn::Data<int32_t>::mulWith(nn::Data<int8_t>* other, nn::Data<int16_t>* target){
    return;
}
```

should use the same template parameter 'T = int8_t', like this:

```
template<> void nn::Data<int8_t>::mulWith(nn::Data<int8_t>* other, nn::Data<int16_t>* target){
    return;
}
```

Also you specialize templated function for templated class in `namespace nn`, so use 2 `template<>` and specialize in correct namespace:

```
#include <cstdint>
namespace nn {
    template<>
    template<>
    void Data<std::int8_t>::mulWith(Data<std::int8_t>* other, Data<std::int16_t>* target){
        return;
    }
}
```

**Note** using `namespace nn` and two `template<>` - one for templated class and one for templated member function.